# Beamer: Custom styles for environments

Tags: beamer, environments

In *beamer*, there are some predefined (colour) styles like *plain*, *theorem*, *definition* and *remark*. My first question is *where can I find the list of these styles?* and the second one is *how can I create my own style?* For instance, I want to apply *orange* colour for remarks.

Comment: Have a look at the end of the file `beamerinnerthemedefault.sty`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's how you can easily define new customized theorem-like blocks; the idea is to define a new style with customized settings, and then use this new style for your structures:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\makeatletter
\def\th@mystyle{%
    \normalfont % body font
    \setbeamercolor{block title example}{bg=orange,fg=white}
    \setbeamercolor{block body example}{bg=orange!20,fg=black}
    \def\inserttheoremblockenv{exampleblock}
  }
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{theorem}[An important theorem]
    Some text
\end{theorem}

\begin{remark}[Some important remark]
    Some text
\end{remark}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Relevant settings for definition of theorem-like structures:

In the file `beamerbasetheorems.sty` you find:

```
\def\th@example{\th@remark}
```

and

```
\ifbeamer@countsect
  \newtheorem{theorem}{\translate{Theorem}}[section]
\else
  \newtheorem{theorem}{\translate{Theorem}}
\fi
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{\translate{Corollary}}
\newtheorem{fact}[theorem]{\translate{Fact}}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{\translate{Lemma}}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{\translate{Problem}}
\newtheorem{solution}[theorem]{\translate{Solution}}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{\translate{Definition}}
\newtheorem{definitions}[theorem]{\translate{Definitions}}

\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{\translate{Example}}
\newtheorem{examples}[theorem]{\translate{Examples}}
```

which means that the `example` style is the same as the remark style; the `plain` style is used for theorems, corollaries, lemmas, problems, solutions. The `definition` style applies to definitions, and the `example` style, to examples.

Also relevant might be the lines

```
\def\inserttheoremheadfont{\the\thm@headfont}
  \def\inserttheoremblockenv{block}

  \def\th@example{%
    \normalfont % body font
    \def\inserttheoremblockenv{exampleblock}
  }
```

which show basically that for the example style, `exampleblock` is used, but for all other theorem-like structures `block` is used.

In `beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty` one finds:

```
\defbeamertemplate{theorem begin}{ams style}
{%
  \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
    {%
      \inserttheoremheadfont
      \inserttheoremname
      \inserttheoremnumber
      \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ (\inserttheoremaddition)\fi%
      \inserttheorempunctuation
    }%
}

\defbeamertemplate{theorem end}{ams style}
{\end{\inserttheoremblockenv}}


\defbeamertemplate{theorem begin}{numbered}
{%
  \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
    {%
      \inserttheoremname
      \inserttheoremnumber
      \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ (\inserttheoremaddition)\fi%
    }%
}

\defbeamertemplate{theorem end}{numbered}
{\end{\inserttheoremblockenv}}


\defbeamertemplate{theorem begin}{normal font}
{
  \normalfont
  \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
  {%
    \inserttheoremname
    \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ (\inserttheoremaddition)\fi%
  }%
}

\defbeamertemplate{theorem end}{normal font}
{\end{\inserttheoremblockenv}}
```