# Change the color of the "remark" environment in Beamer

Tags: beamer, color, lyx, environments

I would like to change the color (bg and fg) of the remark environment in a Beamer document. I have setup my document using:

```
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{crane}
```

I read in some other question that I should use something like:

```
\setbeamercolor{theorem text}{fg=black}
```

or something like

```
\setbeamercolor{block title example}{bg=orange,fg=white}
```

I have tried both, using `remark` or `rem` instead of `theorem` or `example` to no avail. I have to make it clear that I don't want to create a new environment, as I use Lyx and I need to stick to the default "remark" environment, only modified through the preamble.

UPDATE

I have checked that Lyx adds the following definitions to the preamble:

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
     \newtheorem*{defn*}{\protect\definitionname}
  \theoremstyle{remark}
  \newtheorem*{rem*}{\protect\remarkname}
  \theoremstyle{definition}
  \newtheorem*{example*}{\protect\examplename}
  \theoremstyle{plain}
  \newtheorem*{fact*}{\protect\factname}
  \theoremstyle{definition}
  \newtheorem*{problem*}{\protect\problemname}
  \theoremstyle{definition}
  \newtheorem*{xca*}{\protect\exercisename}
```

Is this a Lyx related question instead of a Beamer one?

Comment: Does this question help?: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123951/beamer-custom-styles-for-environments

Comment: Unfortunately no, as a new environment is defined to make the changes. As I want to use Lyx, this is precisely the kind of solutions that I cannot apply.

Comment: There's no `remark` environment predefined in `beamer`.

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo. Check on the UPDATE added to the question.