# Definitions and theorems in beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning, theorems

I have several questions regarding the use of definitions and theorems in the beamer package. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\newtheorem{idea}{Proof idea}

\begin{document}
\section[test]{this is a test}
\frame{
    \begin{tcolorbox}
    \begin{definition} This is a definition. \end{definition}
    \begin{theorem} This is a theorem. \end{theorem}
    \begin{idea} This is a proof idea. \end{idea}
    \begin{proof} This is a proof. \end{proof}
    \end{tcolorbox}
}
\end{document}
```

I have several modifications I would like to add, but I don't really know how to do them myself in Latex.

- I would like to have the definitions and theorems numbered separately.
- I have added the new theorem called `idea`, this is also numbered. But I would like this **not** to be numbered.
- The content of the new theorem `idea` is in italic. How can I remove this?
- Finally, adding `section` or `subsection` in between frames does not print the section title onto the frame. Has this something to do with the default template I am using?
- If it is possible to add sections, I would like the definitions and theorems to be numbered separately, based on the section they are in.

Thank you

Comment: In [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123951/beamer-custom-styles-for-environments), Gonzalo Medina thoroughly explains how to customize the theorem environments. Check it out! 

It doesn't answer everything that you are wondering though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you disable the automatic creation of Theorem blocks by `beamer` and do like the usual way using `amsthm` you can format all easily.

So, the option `notheorems` disable the automatic process and then you have to define the environments by yourself. Thus you can specify the style and the numbering.

```
\documentclass[mathserif,notheorems]{beamer} % option notheorems
\usepackage{amsthm}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered] % to number

\theoremstyle{plain} % insert bellow all blocks you want in italic
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] % to number according to section

\theoremstyle{definition} % insert bellow all blocks you want in normal text
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section] % to number according to section
\newtheorem*{idea}{Proof idea} % no numbered block

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\section[test]{this is a test}
\frame{
    \frametitle[short frame title]{title}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
    \begin{definition} This is a definition. \end{definition}
    \begin{theorem} This is a theorem. \end{theorem}
    \begin{idea} This is a proof idea. \end{idea}
    \begin{proof} This is a proof. \end{proof}
    \end{tcolorbox}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**If you don't want to do by hand as above, then:**

For 1: no solution yet.

For 2 and 3 use

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{idea}{Proof idea}
```

For 5 according to the user guide (pg 119), use the option `envcountsect` within the document class

```
\documentclass[mathserif,envcountsect]{beamer}
```

**Note:** 4 is not related with numbering. Just use inside the `frame`

```
\frametitle[short frame title]{title}
```

to insert a title for it.

Comment: @JNevens, I edited. Please, study it.

Comment: I used the manual solution. Thank you for the extra comments for clarification.

Comment: @JNevens you are welcomed.